# ksqlDB key type struct query

Tags: ksqldb

I have 2 topics in kafka created via oraclecdcsource connector. The source table has one field that is clob, thus i get 2 topics one with table data and one with clob data.  In my clob topic the key looks like

```
Struct{table=XE.MYUSER.AGDA,column=MYCLOB,primary_key=3}
```

I am looking to create 2 streams and then join and push to new topic.  I have created stream on clob topic however when querying the stream I get no data back.

The stream looks like

```
CREATE STREAM AGDA_FORECAST_STREAM_CLOB (
  ROWKEY STRUCT<`table` VARCHAR, `column` VARCHAR, `primary_key` INTEGER> KEY,
  `VALUE` VARCHAR
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'XE.MYUSER.AGDA.MYCLOB',
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'KAFKA',
  KEY_FORMAT = 'JSON'
);
```

I am running query

```
select * from AGDA_FORECAST_STREAM_CLOB EMIT CHANGES;
```

In the ksqlDB logs i can see

> ERROR {"type":0,"deserializationError":{"target":"key","errorMessage":"Failed to deserialize key from topic: XE.MYUSER.AGDA.MYCLOB. Unrecognized token 'Struct': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')","recordB64":null,"cause":["Unrecognized token 'Struct': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')"],"topic":"XE.MYUSER.AGDA.MYCLOB"},"recordProcessingError":null,"productionError":null,"serializationError":null,"kafkaStreamsThreadError":null} (processing.transient_AGDA_FORECAST_STREAM_CLOB_3495042216253612136.KsqlTopic.Source.deserializer)